# Convergence of $z^{1/n}$, where $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Is this reasoning correct? If $z = re^{i\theta}$, 
\begin{equation}
z^{1/n} = r^{1/n}\exp\left(i\frac{\theta}{n}\right)
\end{equation}

and hence,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z^{1/n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} r^{1/n} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right)\right]
\end{equation}
Since $r > 0$ for any non-zero $z$, 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} r^{1/n} = 1
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z^{1/n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right)\right]
\end{equation}
Right hand side does not have a unique value. Therefore, $\{z^{1/n}\}$ does not converge.

Comment: There are two different complex numbers that are equally deserving to be called $z^{1/2}$. Which one do you chose? What about the three options for $z^{1/3}$? And so on. Once you've made your choice for _all_ $n$, you can start taking about whether or not the sequence converges. Fixing a specific $\theta$ once and for all is one way of doing it, and in that case the sequence doors converge to $1$.

Comment: Slight typo in second line of algebra, should read $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z^{1/n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} r^{1/n} \ldots $

Comment: Correction: the sequence _does_ converge to $1$. Damn autocorrect...

Comment: Also, what can you say about $|z|$? if you can state the case for (say) $|z|>1$ then it may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Bacon, I corrected the type.

Comment: @Arthur, does the limit in the last step not go along the unit circle, depending on the exact value of $n$? Sorry, got the point. You are right, the limit is indeed 1.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Arthur, the limit in the last step is indeed $1$. Thus, the sequence converges.